# Two players with the same socre on google game leaderboard

Tags: android, google-play-games

What will happen if two players submit the same score to a google play games leader board? Is there any second parameter that is used to order users with the same score?

I'm going to carry out a competition with a gift for the player from the first place, so I must be clear on this.

I would be grateful for help.

Piotrek.

Comment: Not an actual answer, but I'd assume it's ordered by most recent

Comment: As @Rogue said, you can know who will be the first placer by getting the most recent score. Example: If PlayerA got the score of 100 **first** than PlayerB, then PlayerA wins. You can use the parameter `timeSpan` and get the scores depending on the [value](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/scores/get#parameters) that you will use.